# Force setup.py install to fail on SyntaxError

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils, setup.py

I am trying to test my package on Travis CI, and I want the install process to fail if there are any syntax errors in the install. In particular, I am trying to catch invalid escapes in Python 3.6, which raise a syntax error when doing `python -We:invalid`, but only once, when they are byte compiled (in other words, by the time I run my tests, it is too late to catch these errors in this way).

`setup.py install` reports the syntax errors, but ignores them (doesn't error the install). How can I make it error the install?

Comment: Would running `python -m compileall` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/compileall.html)) on it before installing do the trick? I think this is what distutils is doing internally, but it catches and displays the error without failing.

Comment: @ThomasK well that works, but the messaging around it is truly awful. You have to scroll up to see where the error is from. And to make matters worse, this will also be the thing that fails if there is any syntax error.